# Cannot format swap

Tags: 12.04, swap, format

I was installing ubuntu 12.04 to the side of windows 7 to my friends' computer when I came across the partitioning of the HDD. By accident, I selected swap as the whole partition, which I intended on using it in Linux. Now, because I have three partitions, one for windows loader (~17gb), one for windows os (and data, about 120gb) and a huge swap file (~320gb).
So I couldn't install the linux but when I tried to both from live-ubuntu and from windows 7, I couldn't format the swap file to fat32 or ntfs. I tried using Disk utilites and windows' own formatting app from control panel. Each one recognizes the partition, but when I try to format it, it says an error message.
Also, to top this all of, I tried all the ways in live-ubuntus Disk utilitys to format it with no success. But the thing is, when I put back the boot order to launch windows, the windows doesn't boot at all! But I had to go so I couldn't investigate the problem further, but I'm feeling pretty quilty since it might be that i ruined my friends computer...

I know my explanation seems a bit confusing, but thats because I'm not in front of the computer and I am explaining all from my memory. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: try to delete using gparted before formatting.

Comment: i tried to belete it both with windows and with linuxes disk utility, does deleting with gparted differ from the disk utility and windows?

Comment: Load the the live Ubuntu and open a terminal type `sudo fdisk -l` and add the output to your question.

Comment: okay will do as soon as i get my hands into that computer, probably tomorrow morning, thanks in advance!

Comment: it seems that the computers whole hdd has been completely wiped... :o no idea how... it seems that i have to reinstall windows 7 too. disk utility shows me nothing but free 500gb space and the command sudo swapoff /dev/sda doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1):

Use the command swapoff on the partition before trying to use it. Linux Live CD try to probe a swap partition and mount it while booting.

Usually the command to swapoff is

```
sudo swapoff /dev/sdxx
```

Where xx is disk and partition number (best found by `sudo swapon -s` (-s stands for *summary*)).